# Use lean in mongoose with callback

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, callback

I am trying to use `lean` in my mongoDB query but the problem I am facing is that I don't use `.exec()` method. I use callback implementation like below

```
model.find({user_id: mobile_no }, {'_id':0, 'type':1}, {sort: {dateTime: -1}, skip: page*page_size, limit: page_size + 1}, function(err, docs) {
     if (err) {
                
     } else {

     }
});
```

but in most documentation,everyone uses `lean` with `.exec()` like below

```
.lean().exec()
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I use `lean` using my callback implementation or I would have to use `.exec()` implementation in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `.exec()` and callbacks:

```
model.find(...).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
  ...
});
```

See also [the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean), where one of the examples does the same.

Comment: yes but as i am not using `exec()` can i use `lean()` without using `exec()` because otherwise i will have to change code everywhere just because of exec().

Comment: I don't understand: you already have to change your code everywhere because you want to use `.lean()`, so what's the issue with adding an additional `.exec()`? Like my answer states: you can still use callbacks using `.exec()`, you don't have to use promises if you don't want to.

Comment: ok thanks i just want to use my syntax, there is no extra problem thanks anyways.

Comment: actually time taken by query is still little bit same, there is no significant difference coming ?? Can you tell me why this is hapening.

Comment: My guess would be that your query just is slow, which `lean` won't solve (it only skips the step where Mongoose converts the MongoDB results into Mongoose documents).

Comment: @FluffyNights oh I think that's actually _exactly_ what the OP is looking for. Feel free to post your own answer! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
model.find({user_id: mobile_no }, {'_id':0, 'type':1}, {sort: {dateTime: -1}, skip: page*page_size, limit: page_size + 1}, function(err, docs) {
     if (err) {

     } else {

     }
}).lean();
```

You have to write .lean() at the end of the query :3