# bson.deserializeObject taking up too much CPU for seemingly simple query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I have a mongoDB collection of ~400 documents. And I have a REST method that for now just returns the result of the .find({}) query on this collection (i'm using mongoose btw). When I tried to benchmark this method with ~40 requests per second, I found that response times are horrible (~10s), and after I profiled the app, the flamegraph looked like this

[image]

Performance become tolerable when the query pulls like 20-30 objects, but if it gets over 100, the app just gets stuck on deserializing the results. Is it normal? Can I do something about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to profile BSON.deserialize in isolation.

Comment: I don't think that there's a problem with the function itself, it just get called very often, and I try to understand why this is happening. I've read a blog post where author encountered the same problem - bson.deserializeObject getting called a lot, but his problem was that he was querying a large collection without an index. Here I'm just pulling all the docs from a small-ish collection.

Comment: Of course not, but it is being called recursively, e.g. https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/2.0.0/lib/bson/parser/deserializer.js#L209 so testing it in isolation may shed some light whether it is massive documents to deserialize, limited resources, blocked loop, GC, etc or 0x gives you misleading report.

Comment: I checked that documents themselves are pretty small with no embedded docs, but thanks, this sound reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'lean' method in mongoose might help you.

'lean' method tells mongoose not to convert objects from db to mongoose schema objects but a plain JavaScript objects which in turn increase deserialize speed.

Example

```
Students.find({name: 'Josh'}).lean().exec((err, docs) => {
     ...
});
```

See also
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/high-performance-find-query-using-lean-in-mongoose-2/
[Use lean in mongoose with callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974330/use-lean-in-mongoose-with-callback)